# T-SQL: Delete records based on the value of the 24th record of a Distinct date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have a table with many timestamped entries (Timestamp column named 'DATED').

I periodically want to delete older entries from the table older than the last 24 distinct dates in the DATED column.

So I'm trying to write a delete query
who's where clause resolves to (DATED < [The 24th Distinct Date from DATED])

I don't want to design the query to delete records older than x days.
I want that table to always maintain 24 record sets even if they are old records.

Any suggetsions?

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of `Coomon Table Expression` and `Window Function` you can get what you desired.

- [TSQL Ranking Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

For SQL Server 2005

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY convert(varchar(20), DATED, 102)
                                ORDER BY DATED DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
DELETE FROM recordList
WHERE rn > 24
```

For SQL Server 2008+

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(DATED AS DATE)
                                ORDER BY DATED DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
DELETE FROM recordList
WHERE rn > 24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN
(
SELECT ID
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE DESC) RN
  FROM TABLE
 ) A
WHERE RN > 24
)
```